# My ticketing system for a server is not running on_message(message)

Tags: python, discord.py

```
import discord
client = discord.Client()
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('ALERT: {0.user} has connected and is now ready for use.'.format(client))



@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.startswith('$request-whitelisting'):
        print("1")
        x = author.has_permissions(administrator)
        print(author)
        if x == False:
            print("2")
            await message.channel.send("OK, I am now alerting the admins who can approve your request.")
            channel = bot.getchannel(784863111579435019)
            idiot = message.author()
            await message.channel.send("Alert: "+idiot+" has requested whitelist.")



client.run('Token')
```

That's the code - It won't work, I have tried to get it to only do that and then run the bot and it refuses, I have tried moving stuff, flagging issues using print() but in the end, the function is not being run.
All I am getting out of the shell is the startup message:
`ALERT: Bot#NumID has connected and is now ready for use.`

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
import discord
intents = Intents.default()
intents.members = True

client = discord.Client(intents = intents)

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('ALERT: {0.user} has connected and is now ready for use.'.format(client))



@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.startswith('$request-whitelisting'):
        print("1")
        x = author.has_permissions(administrator)
        print(author)
        if x == False:
            print("2")
            await message.channel.send("OK, I am now alerting the admins who can approve your request.")
            channel = bot.getchannel(784863111579435019)
            idiot = message.author()
            await message.channel.send("Alert: "+idiot+" has requested whitelist.")



client.run('Token')
```